# How does Google Appengine recommend we Certificate Signing Request (CSR) for SSL on Custom Domain?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to purchase a certificate, and the provider (rapidSSL) is asking me to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR). However, I can't find anything in the appengine documentation on how to create this?

Anybody have a clear solution they used? Or can Google weigh in on how we do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Certificate Authority provides details on how to generate a Certificate Signing Request in a form they prefer to use. You should follow the guides provided by the CA on how to get a certificate for use with Apache as this will generate the correct certificate and will also provide steps to generate a CSR.

Something to also be aware of it some CAs instructions generate keys in an encrypted form. If this happens you can decrypt the key using openssl by running this command: openssl rsa -in encrypted.key -out unencrypted.key

Comment: Here is the RapidSSL info fot the apache CSR creation https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=so6411

Answer (score 1):

Various programs exist to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR.) I used 'openssl' on a linux machine to generate the Key and CSR.

1) I generated an Unencrypted PEM encoded RSA private key as specified by Google's SSL for a Custom Domain (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl)

```
cd $HOME
openssl genrsa -out rsa_private_key.key 2048
```

2) Use the 'rsa_private_key.key' to generate the required  Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file.

```
openssl req -new -key rsa_private_key.key -out request.csr
```

You will be asked the following questions:

```
   Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]: US
   State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]: Illinois
   Locality Name (eg, city) []: Chicago
   Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: Chicago Company, Ltd.
   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: IT
   Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []: checkout.customedomain.com
   Email Address []:
```

I ignored two additional questions and everything worked fine. The 'request.csr' located on your home directory ($HOME) is the CSR file needed by the Certificate Authority provider to generate your certificate(s). Again, it doesn't have to be openssl: Many tools for various platforms are supported by providers. Just keep in mind Google's requirements.

**A side note regarding Custom Domains:**

Make sure your CUSTOM DOMAIN includes a subdomain or 'Full Qualified Domain Name.' The 'www.' is considered a subdomain and it's ALWAYS required for ssl in Google Appengine (10/2014.) So in my example if I wanted SSL at customedomain.com I would add 'www.customedomain.com' You can re-direct your naked domain to your Full Qualified Domain Name.

Google Appengine DOES NOT provide SSL support for naked domains like: https://customedomain.com

Comment: Update: It seems to support naked domains now